# How to download file from Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-worker, js-xlsx

In the project(that was writen on Angular4.3) we use [xlsx](https://docs.sheetjs.com/demos/demos/angular2#sheetjs-js-xlsx) to create xlsx/csv tables for download by user. The problem that we faced is when we try to export a big amount of data, original json file can be 100+Mb and converted xlsx/csv file can be 28Mb, and all this conversion operation is processing on client side, it use all resources on main thread. I try to add web wroker to move all process to another thread and when a try to download created file from wroker I get an error:

> export.worker.bundle.js:2 Uncaught Error: cannot save file test.xlsx

Example code to adding worker by click:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const worker = new Worker('./export.worker.bundle.js');
  const payload = {
   data: [
   { name: 'Moran', role: 'back' },
   { name: 'Alain', role: 'front' },
   { name: 'Tony', role: 'back' },
   { name: 'Mike', role: 'back' },
   { name: 'Abo', role: 'back' },
   { name: 'Toni', role: 'back' }
   ]
  };
  worker.postMessage(payload);
  worker.onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log(e.data);
  // worker.terminate();
  };
 });
```

Worker code:

```
(function() {
 const XLSX = require('xlsx');
 const utils = require('xlsx').utils;
 const self = this;

 self.onmessage = function(e) {
   console.log('Worker data: ', e.data);
   const fileName = 'test.xlsx';

   const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(e.data.data);
   const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
   XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'test');

   XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName);
   self.postMessage('Process complete!');
 };
})();
```

> XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename, write_opts) attempts to write wb to filename. In browser-based environments, it will attempt to force a client-side download.

This line **XLSX.writeFile** attempt to start download and it failed on it and also this operation is taking all resources from thread as I understood.

Is posible to start file download from worker? or I need to go back to main thread for it ?